# How to calculate the expected rotational speed of a star

Tags: space, hard-science, stars

I am working on fictional stars, and I want to have as many points about them as I can, and most things I found relatively easy, except for rotational speed.

I am not sure exactly how to find at what speed a star should be rotating in relation to its mass and spectral class. I found a small list of a few ones on wikipedia, but it doesn't help that much as it doesn't include the exact class I am looking for at the moment.

So, how is it that one can estimate what rotational velocity a star should have given the parameters. The parametres I know include Mass, Stellar Class, Radius, Density, Volume, Luminosity, Expected Maximum Age, Current Age (technically it changes as my world takes place over a long period, but the difference is in like, thousands of years, not billions) and Temperature.

I am aware massive outliers can exist, like Achernar, but I just need help finding like, the average, expected range so that I can use believable values.

Your help is much appreciated. Equations and citations would be beneficial, which is why I used the Hard Science tag.

**Edit:**

As requested by Neil Iyer, here is a random one of my stars so you can try answering that. I still do request a generalized answer, though.

- Class: F2.2V

  Mass: 1.35

  Radius: 1.187

  Density: 0.808

  Luminosity: 3.322

  Temperature: 7158 K

  Age: 3.6 Gyr

Mass, Radius, Density, and Luminosity are based on the Sun.

**Edit 2:**

One more specification, I am looking for equatorial velocity.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer because after years on this Stack I can't remember once seeing a question about star rotation. I'd be curious to know if star rotation has any meaning for planetary orbits and habitability?

Comment: You can't give any quantitative data without you giving some. Why don't you state all those parameters you know by editing your question and adding them?

Comment: I mean, my question is moreso about finding generalized formulae concerning the subject, for me to use the equations myself. Not just an exact answer for one situation. Which would just lead to me needing to make hundreds of seperate questions. While doing a generalized formula or set of formulae could help me do it for all of my stars. But I guess I would put a random one of them up there.

Comment: @NeilIyer OP isn't asking for "quantitative data", they're asking after a model of stellar physics. Adding extraneous details distracts from the focus of the Q imo.

Comment: @BMF Oh, I did not realize. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Hmm, I think there might be a range of angular speeds for a given mass, yet if a proto-stellar cloud did not revolve, and it did not have enough mass to turn the star into a black hole, the resultant star will not revolve at all. About the highest revolution speed vs mass/radius, I expect as much as zero effective gravity on the equator of the star could be reachable, or a tad less since that mass would otherwise be blown away by the stellar wind. That is, the exact available angular speed range would just need to satisfy integrity criteria for being too fast, and mass criteria for being slow.

Comment: Not really an answer, but a simplistic beginning: this [classroom document from NASA](https://spacemath.gsfc.nasa.gov/sun/4Page1.pdf) gets the ball rolling by claiming star rotation speed is a factor of both age (young=fast, old=slow) and mass (high=fast, low=slow). But I can also discern from that document (disclaimer: I'm not a celestial mechanic) that there won't be an easy equation. It might be simpler to find a similar star to your fictional star and simply use that star's rotation, if known.

Comment: A second problem is that stellar rotation [varies by latitude](https://www.nasa.gov/image-article/solar-rotation-varies-by-latitude/) as well as depth. We can ignore depth for the purposes of your question, but it would help if you [edit] your post to indicate (I hope) that you're only interested in the equatorial velocity. (I found it interesting that the velocity *slows down* as you get closer to the poles.)

Comment: Yeah, will do. (Though I can make a second question for the change in rotation at depth after this gets answered)

Comment: OK, I think I found the solution, but it's discussing math I haven't used since college 35 years ago and I couldn't hope to process any of it without dusting off a textbook. [It's here](https://www.astro.umd.edu/~jph/Stellar_Rotation.pdf) and it's messy. It should be messy, because stars don't have a single angular velocity. That PDF goes into a lot more than just rotation, so it's a valuable resource, but may heaven smile on you as you start turning the arithmetic crank. I'm voting again for finding a similar star....

Comment: And if someone wants to take the link in my previous comment and turn it into an answer, bless you, too. I don't have the time to figure out all the MathJax necessary to replicate even a portion of the document in an answer.

Comment: Yeah, definitely needs to be simplified a lot to just give the equatorial velocity, as a lot of this is going into how to find it for different lattitudes, thus accounts for the necessary non-uniformity of stellar rotation in respect to lattitude.  Main thing confusing me is using a lot of variables without explaining what the variable is, it is very clearly intended for those that know a lot about the subject and the variable shorthands used already.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an accurate formula that provides what you are after. Your best bet may be to use observational data and extrapolate, the following may be of some use (see p12-13) https://assets.cambridge.org/97805217/72181/sample/9780521772181ws.pdf

Answer (score 2):

### Unfortunately, you cannot.*

Angular momentum is an independant parameter of the system, like mass, or age. You cannot derive what it *should* be from other independant parameters, unlike a dependant parameter like temperature or radius. A star can have any angular velocity*, just like it could be at any age, or have any mass, within limits. It all depends on what the initial angular momentum of the cloud of gas it came from. While there may be trends based on mass and age, they do not effect the actual value. For example, while older stars will tend to be slower than younger stars, there's no reason to expect a young star not to have no rotation whatsoever.

*While the actual value of an independant paramaeter is not calculatable and must be observed, the minimum and maximum values can be. A star of a certain mass will have a maximum age, and one of a certain luminosity will have a maximum mass. Taking the link posted in a comment by JBH as a source, the break-up velocity of a star is given by:

$v_{max} = (\frac{2}{3}\frac{GM}{r_p})^\frac{1}{2}$

Where $r_p$ is the polar radius. A star can have any equatorial velocity between 0 and this value. For your example star, the value is 380 km/s, or 188 times the sun's equatorial velocity.

I would say pick a value between these extremes, but as you might have guessed it is not a uniform distribution, and most stars are no where near the extremes. But any given star *could* be anywhere in the range. This is because, to reiterate, the angular momentum a star starts with is not dependant on the mass it starts with (unlike, for example, the temperature, radius, and luminosity, which all *can* be calculated from age and mass). It is one of the starting values which must be plugged into the model.

What you can do is take observations of many star rotations for a given set of parameters (age and mass, spectral class, etc.) and fit a function to this distribution, and take the peak of this function as your average, but I wouldn't expect a very tight distribution around this average.

Either way the answer is to use values from observation. As slarty pointed out, here is a table of average values based on spectral class that you can use as a first approximation: [The distribution of angular momentum among main sequence stars](https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1965Obs....85..166M/0000167.000.html)

Based on that, a good approximate value may be 50 km/s, about ~25 solar velocities.